# Do "lettuce" and "let us" have the same pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching a video about food and I feel that "lettuce" and "let us"are pronounced the same way, Am I right?

If yes, what can I do to prevent confusion especially while dealing with customers? I'm not a native English speaker but I serve native speakers.

Comment: English has many more homophones besides _lettuce_ and _let us_. I've never heard anyone who mistook "Lettuce pray" when "Let us pray" was said, and I don't know of anyone who thought I asking for "Romaine let us" when I was trying to buy leafy greens at the grocery store. I can't see why this would ever raise "confusion."

Comment: @J.R. I just learned this word yesterday. The video was describing the components of a sandwich. There was a pause in the speech. Then, the speaker said "lettuce". So I thought that this is a new sentence that starts with "Let us". That's why I asked if native speakers may feel confused in some situations, or is it just me because I'm not native.

Comment: @user2824371 - If the speaker was talking about what goes into a sandwich, interpreting it as **lettuce** is much more natural.  It's possible that the speaker was making a pun, or beginning a sentence like "Let us...consider whether mayonnaise is desirable or not" but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do have the same pronunciation (at least by many people from California). It's actually the basis of many puns.

To prevent confusion use "let us" or "lettuce" in the correct context.

Answer (score 5):

I am British and I speak what is sometimes called Received Pronunciation or "BBC English", and for me, "lettuce" and "let us" are definitely not homophones. The final syllable of 'lettuce" rhymes with the -ice parts of justice, notice, avarice, etc, while 'us' is spoken to rhyme with bus, fuss, pus, etc. This is also true of most UK regional dialects, with the possible exception of North East ('Geordie').

[British and US pronunciation of 'lettuce' audio samples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/lettuce)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that, to many in the US, the -ice parts of _justice, notice, averice_, etc., sounds very much like the -uce in _lettuce_, and the -us in _bus_. So, I believe you, but, by reading this answer, I can't figure out how you say those words.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Made me add a "California" qualifier to my post.

Comment: Not only different pronunciation but different emphasis too: In "lettuce" the stress is on the first syllable, in "let us" they are even.

Comment: yeah but you can make them rhyme if you want to, especially for a good r4 pun. Let us put some Lettuce in this salad.

Answer (score 1):

In my idiolect, the last vowel in "lettuce" is \ɪ\, while the vowel in "us" is \ʌ\, so they aren't perfect homophones. Even if they were, context should help distinguish them; for one thing, they are different parts of speech. Also, "let us" in the sense of presenting a suggestion is generally contracted to "let's". If you really want to distinguish them, you can move the \t\ to the second syllable of "lettuce" (leh-tice). This isn't quite the standard pronunciation, but is more distinct. And when saying "let us", you can pause between "let" and "us".